# Change Bundle ID when "upgrading" to an organization from individual dev account?

Tags: ios-appstore, apple-id

I created an app 2 years ago and have the bundle ID with my name in the ID (com.joshXXXX.YYYYY). I did not have a business at the time and I read it was okay to use my name. Fast forward to today I have a small team and feel the need to change my individual account to an organization. I would like to also set my Bundle ID as it should be for good practice (com.companyname.xxxxx).

Could this change be done with the account change to an organization or do I have to make a whole new app with a new Bundle ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is somewhere in between actually.

If you setup a new organization account while keeping your individual dev account, you can transfer the app from one account to the other. In this process it is possible for you to choose a new bundle-ID for the app as an update of the app.

However, the end-users devices will treat it as a "new app", which means that it will require them to update the app and the app will have "forgotten" any stored credentials in Keychain, and if you have any kind of sharing with other apps you have made, that group membership will be broken.

Comment: Thank you @jksoegaard, appreciate the info on how it would effect the current users too. If the current users see "update" on the app store, that won't be to much of an inconvenience on the end users side, aside from the forgetting of their credentials. The last thing I want for current users is to uninstall and re-download the app.

Comment: @jksoegaard: The bundle ID is the only thing that identifies an app on the app store. Even after migrating an to a new account, if we change the bundle id it essentially becomes a new app. If we change the bundle id of the app on the new account, how will app store know to update an app deployed with a different bundle id? Reference: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/7401
Have you done this on an already deployed app on the app store?

Comment: Today you cannot make it so that devices that have en existing app update it to an entirely new app. The user will have to install the new app. However, you can have the old app popup a messsage at launch stating that the user needs to reinstall in order to force the user to do so.